# Pass JSON object as props with useNavigate function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a kendo grid and when a user clicks on a row he is navigated to '/details' url. I was wondering is it possible to send props (whole row data) with the useNavigate function? This is my code:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
....
....
const BooleanCell = (props) => {
          return (
<td onClick={()=>{navigate('/details')}}><HiCursorClick/>{props.dataItem.sn_template_id}</td>
                 )
        }
```

So when a user clicks on this row he is redirected to /details url. The thing I want is to send props, which contains a JSON object with multiple key-value pairs, to that detail url. Is it possible with useNavigate and if not, what is the best solution to my problem?

Comment: You've updated and added new details to your question, which sort of changes the scope of what you are asking. What sort of JSON data are you wanting/trying to pass to the routed component? Does it need to be sent in route state or can you use a path param, i.e. `"/details/:detailId"` and the routed component uses the `detailId` param to access the JSON data? If your question is *actually* more than just "how do I send data when using the `navigate` function" then please edit to include all relevant code and details you have an issue and need help with.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want access to that data (sn_template_id) when you get to details page? You should use query param for passing that data, and then extracting that param when on details page.

e.g. :

```
navigate(`/details?id=${props.dataItem.sn_template_id}`)
```

and then extract that info on the details page.

I don't know which version of React-Router you're using so it depends which hook you use to extract it. But it will be `useLocation()` most likely.

Comment: The `useParams` hook only accesses defined route path params, not any queryString parameters. You likely meant the [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams) hook.

Comment: No Veljko, in my props I have a JSON that I want to access when I get to details page, so this doesn't help.